# PATCH неверной схемы

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, eve

У меня есть следующая схема (часть схемы):

```
{
    "item_title": "block",
    "schema": {
       
        "next_blocks": {
            'type': 'dict',
            'required': True,
            "oneof_schema": [
                {
                    'final': {
                        'required': True,
                        'type': 'boolean',
                        'nullable': False,
                        'check_with': boolean_validator,
                    },
                },
                {
                    "unary": {
                        "type": "objectid",
                        "nullable": True,
                        'required': True,
                        "data_relation": storage.get_relation(resource="block", embeddable=True, field="_id"),
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    }
}
```

Я создаю документ с полем `final` и после этого я обновляю документ методом PATCH с полем `unary`. Затем у меня есть документ с полями `final` и `unary`. Это неверно, поэтому у меня задана `oneof_schema`, т.е. должна вернуться 422 ошибка, так как изменение некорректно.

Есть [несколько](https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#editing-a-document-patch) [мест](https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#data-integrity-and-concurrency-control), где упоминается о том, как работает `PATCH` в `EVE`.

Comment: Я думаю, это не баг. Правило определяет, какими типами может быть next_blocks, и при патче формально проверку проходит. А вот ограничения "в целом документе поле должно быть только одно - final или unary", это уже совсем другое, и правило не про это. Но это не точно. Есть ссылка на документацию? То что я нашел, оставляет как раз эту неясность.

Comment: @TotalPusher я не находил описания этого кейса

Comment: Есть документация? Покажите ссылку, будем смотреть вместе. То что я сам нашел - не однозначно

Comment: @TotalPusher добавил.

Comment: Нет, ссылку на oneof_schema. Как работает PATCH я знаю, как работает EVE - не нужно знать, проблема в oneof_schema я думаю.